# Regex expression throwing error in IE 11

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find all the '+' characters in a string and replace that with spaces (' '). Code works fine in Chrome/Firefox but breaks in IE. What modification do I need to get it working in IE?

```
str = str.replace(new RegExp(/\+/, 'g'), ' ');
```

Error:
TypeError: Syntax error in regular expression

Comment: Use `str = str.replace(/\+/g, ' ');`

Comment: I am using "str = str.replace(new RegExp(/\+/, 'g'), ' ');" but somehow the escape character got escaped in question :)

Comment: @AlexK - Your answer is correct.

Comment: Aye but what he has should work as well so its not the ctor/literal issue thats the problem

Comment: Please describe *but breaks in IE* ?

Comment: This is the error message:
"TypeError: Syntax error in regular expression" at that specific line

Comment: @AlexK.: IE does not support regex literal inside RegExp constructor like that. That should be either a regex literal `.replace(/\+/g, ' ')` or `.replace(new RegExp("\\+", 'g'), ' ');`

Comment: @Wiktor, that works. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Chrome/Firfox that now support ECMAScript 6 support regex literals inside a RegExp constructor. IE - as of now - still does not support that.

See [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-sets):

> Starting with ECMAScript 6, `new RegExp(/ab+c/, 'i')` no longer throws a TypeError (`"can't supply flags when constructing one RegExp from another"`) when the first argument is a `RegExp` and the second flags argument is present. A new `RegExp` from the arguments is created instead.

This will work in Chrome:

```js
console.log("1+2".replace(new RegExp(/\+/, 'g'), ' '));
```

In IE, it is safer to use a regex literal, or a string inside RegExp constructor:

```js
console.log("1+2".replace(new RegExp("\\+", 'g'), ' '));
console.log("1+2".replace(/\+/g, ' '));
```

For this static pattern, consider using the regex literal notation (`/\+/g`). If you are planning to use a variable inside a pattern, then you will need the constructor notation (do not forget to double backslashes there).